# Is it fair for all customers?

Tags: probability

One seller here holds an event announcing that it will send out 1000 gifts. People could register on its website and get a chance to draw. He/She will immediately know whether he/she win the gift.

My question is: is there a fair algorithm for the seller that when the event ends, all people found their winning chance were same? Or what is the best can do?

Comment: Do we know the total number of participants in advance?

Comment: Is he guaranteed to send out 1000 gifts? If so, then there is a possibility that only 1000 people register, in which case the algorithm would have to always award a prize to the first 1000 people, which of course will fail if there are more than 1000 people who register.

Comment: Suppose all $N$ people in the town have a unique id, and randomly $1000$ of those are chosen.  Now you know when each person logs on, whether he/ she has won...  Of course this assumes $N$ is known and all people register (otherwise 1000 gifts wont go out).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a little careful when tossing out words like "fair". There are already some unfair things - I must know of the promotion, I must have internet access etc.

However, if we define fair as:

- Every person who registers while the promotion is occurring has an equal chance of winning.
- The promotion stops when the 1000th prize is awarded
- There promotion continues until all 1000 prizes are given out and/or ends at a given time (in which case not all prizes are given out).

A fair algorithm is then:

1. The promoter estimates the number of expected participants $N$.
2. When a participant registers a random number is generated between $1$ and $N$. (A pseudo-number generator seeded with the date/time of registration would be suitably random).
3. If the random number is $1$ then the person wins a prize and the prize pool is reduced.
4. Repeat until the time runs out or the prize pool is empty.